# What is this cinematic story telling technique called?

Tags: editing

When actors are in a scene, as their time comes to an end in that scene/location, they will discuss action that needs to happen at another location.

The next scene is rarely what the actors were discussing.  Most usually this next scene will play out with different actors in another storyline.  If the first scene is particularly compelling, the storyline of the first scene will usually continue after this second scene.

Is there a name for this technique?  'Alternating storylines' for lack of a better term.  I figured it might be something that gets taught in film school.  Taught in Suspense 101, maybe.

Comment: This happens in a lot of novels, too. It's not just cinematic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cross-cutting sounds like what you are talking about:

> Cross-cutting is an editing technique most often used in films to establish action occurring at the same time, and often in the same place.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting